# umrah ihram sheets

Tags: clothing, umrah

Salam alaik. please I need help on an issue regarding ihram sheets, is it permissible for one who took off his ihram sheets after umrah to re-wear them after somedays to perform dawaf nafila Jazakhallahu khairan. Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: Please consider adding some more information: What do you mean by wearing them to continue your normal life, do you mean in Mekka when you still haven't ended your 'umrah, do you mean at home once you are back from 'umrah... please clearify. You can wear them anywhere, but usually when you finish your task of 'umrah and hajj it is sunnah to take them off, by the way you would wear the same when you are dead.

Comment: Jazakhallahu khairan what i mean was if it permissible to wear them after umrah while still in makkah

Comment: @AhmedMahmud edit your post and add this info as comments will be deleted once, while post may stay if they are on-topic etc.. Each post has an edit link use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wearing the sheets of cloth as they are is permissible at any time, as long as they cover the 'awrah. However, they should not be work in order to deceive the authorities (e.g. if the authorities are only permitting people in the state of ihram to enter the mataf area).

Comment: jazakhallahu khairan